# Prevent access to Dashboard section from the address bar

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I have a member login on my site. If the information is correct, he can enter it in the dashboard.But from the address bar into the dashboar section, How Can I prevent him from entering?, so I can prevent the entry to the dashboard section without the member login

**File Name:Member.php**

**My Codes**

***Session and Index set location***

```
$member =  $this->member_model->get($where);

        if($member) {
            //Dashboard..

            //session user => session indis set..

            $this->session->set_userdata("member", $member);

            redirect(base_url("dashboard"));
```

**FİLE NAME:Dashboard.php**

**This is the dashboard Code Section.**

**My Codes**

```
 public function index()
    {

        //In session, redirect the user to the signin section, if any.

        $member = $this->session->userdata("member");

        if(!$member){
            redirect(base_url("Member/signin_form"));
        }else{
            $this->load->view("dashboard");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with recent versions of CI, but this looks like it already should do that.

Comment: try to use if(!isset($member))

Comment: Did you call the index function in dashoboard.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Add this code at the top of your Dashboard.php:

```
 if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
        // redirect them to your desired location
        header('location:../Member.php');
        exit;
    }
```